# Passing data from Child to Parent using only Javascript on VueJS

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I know use `$emit` to pass data from child to parent components on VueJS but I want get that value on javascript function. My scenario is:

**Parent**

```
 created () {
    this.$on('getValue', function (params) {
      console.log('PARAMS: ' + params)
    })
  },
```

**Child**

```
methods: {
checkBoxChanged (index) {
      this.$emit('getValue', 'some value')
    },
}
```

But it ins't works. Using html I can set on Parent using something like: **(I'VE REASONS TO CAN'T DO IT!)**

```
<template>
  <div>
    <h1>{{ message }}</h1>
    <child v-on:listenerChild="listenerChild"/>
  </div>
</template>
```

But I need do this using just javascript.

Answer (score -1):

That's how you can pass data from child to parent:

```js
Vue.component('child-component', {
  template: 
  `<button type="button" @click="emitClick">
    Click to emit event to parent component
   </button>`,
  
  methods: {
    emitClick() {
       this.$emit('buttonClicked', 'Magic from child component!');
     },
  },
});

Vue.component('parent-component', {
  template:
    `<div>
      <div>Child data is: {{ childData }}</div>
      <child-component @buttonClicked="handleClick" />
     </div>`,
  
  data() {
    return {
      childData: 'empty',
    };
  },
  
  methods: {
    handleClick(data) {
      this.childData = data;
    },
  },
});

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <parent-component />
</div>
```